# procedure to update selected columns in a table

Tags: sql, postgresql, stored-procedures, sql-update

**POSTGRESQL**

Case Background -There is a table named MasterSIM to which details are to be added usin.csv file  via Nodered.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE "master_SIMs".simiccidlink1(IMEI bigint, iccid text, phonenumber bigint,  apn text, "Operator" text, isesim boolean, ism2m boolean, mdi bigint, imsi integer)
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql' AS 
$BODY$
declare
-- retval text
begin 
if (length(IMEI) = 15) then
    if (master_packs.luhn_verify(IMEI) is True) then
        update "master_SIMs".list SET "ICCID" = iccid, "phoneNumber" = phonenumber, "APN" = apn, "operator" = "Operator", "isESIM" = isesim, "isM2M" = ism2m, "MDI" = mdi, "IMSI" = imsi where IMEI = "serialNumber";   
    end if;
end if;
end;
$BODY$;


CALL "master_SIMs".simiccidlink1(352277818466409, 'iccid1', '8018466080', 'apn1', 'operator1', '0', '0', 123456789987653, 12354);
select * from "master_SIMs".list;
```

error I am getting is -
**ERROR:  procedure master_SIMs.simiccidlink1(unknown, unknown, unknown, unknown, integer, integer, integer, integer, bigint) does not exist
LINE 2: CALL "master_SIMs".simiccidlink1('iccid1', '8018466080', 'ap...
^
HINT:  No procedure matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
SQL state: 42883
Character: 7**

I am new to this - please GUIDE.
I have tried all possible ways to fix it.

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but: you should really avoid those dreaded quoted identifiers. They are much more trouble than they are worth it. https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don%27t_Do_This#Don.27t_use_upper_case_table_or_column_names

Comment: That is the error I am getting. 

ERROR:  procedure master_SIMs.simiccidlink1(unknown, unknown, unknown, unknown, integer, integer, unknown, unknown, unknown) does not exist
LINE 1: CALL "master_SIMs".simiccidlink1('1234332', '113', '222', '2...
             ^
HINT:  No procedure matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
SQL state: 42883
Character: 6

Comment: @a-horse-with-no-name
I have fixed the quoted identifier issue, and editted in the question. Still it says there is he type cast error. 

Please could you guide.

Comment: `ERROR: function length(bigint) does not exist` <<-- your IMEI argument has data type bigint. There is no length() function for bigints. (there is one for text)

Comment: An IMEI is not a BIGINT, it is 15 decimal digits: 14 digits plus a check digit. And as of 2004, the format of the IMEI is AA-BBBBBB-CCCCCC-D, although it may not always be displayed this way.

Comment: so what datatype shall I put in for IMEI?